# What is the actual type of Expression<Func<..>>.Compile()?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I wanted to make sure that expressions don't get compiled multiple times, so I tried to memoize them in a dictionary:

```
    static Dictionary<int, object> dict = new Dictionary<int, object>();
    static T testmethod<T>(Expression<Func<T>> e) {
        object result;
        if (!dict.TryGetValue(1, out result)) {
            result = e.Compile();
            dict.Add(1, e);
        }

        return ((Func<T>)result)();
    }


    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var firstTest = testmethod(() => default(int));
        var secondTest = testmethod(() => default(int));
     }
```

While the first call of `testmethod` works without errors, the second call crashes with an `InvalidCastException` (translation):

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`1[System.In32]] cannot be converted to System.Func`1[System.In32]
```

The message suggests that the expression didn't get compiled at all but why does it work the first time then? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`e.Compile` returns a `Func<T>` but you're adding the source `Expression<Func<T>>` to the dictionary which you're then trying to cast to `Func<T>` on the second call. Add the compiled `Func<T>` to `dict` instead:

```
dict.Add(1, result);
```

Comment: Looks like I did the same error twice, while rewriting the testmethod by hand. How did I miss this? Thank you, will accept your answer in 5min (SO time limit)

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> result = e.Compile();
> dict.Add(1, e);
> ```

You are not adding the delegate (compiled expression) to the dictionary, but the expression itself. In the second line, replace `e` with `result`.

> ```
> return ((Func<T>)result)();
> ```

Here you're expecting `result` to be a delegate. That'll only be the case when the dictionary didn't contain a value for key `1` and the above two lines got executed. If the dictionary did contain a value (on the 2nd iteration), then `result` will be an expression, due to `dict.Add(1, e);`.

PS: You might have caught that error earlier by constraining your dictionary's values to type `Delegate` instead of `object`.